# Structure Grid for a building with irregular shape

Tags: structures

I am making a building block with the shape as outlined in yellow in the attached capture, as for the structure I am not sure how to place the loadbearing poles and I could use some help [image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.